# How can I solve the Maven error distributionManagement.status must not be specified

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm trying to download the maven-appassembler-plugin and all its dependencies to use offline.

I'm running the command:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:copy -Dartifact=org.codehaus.mojo:appassembler-maven-plugin:1.10
```

and getting the error

```
[ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be specified. @ line 240, column 13: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:1.0-alpha-4
```

The same command worked when I tried to download a different dependency: the maven-assembly-plugin.

Any idea where this error is coming from?

Thanks,
Eyal

Comment: I would recommend to make you build which uses the plugins and afterwards go offline and you can rebuilt.. apart from that I strongly recommend to start using a repository manager which helps in such situations a lot...furthermore it would be helpful to have full error log and not only a single line....

Comment: I simply found the pom in local repository, deleted distributionManagement tag, completed copy-dependencies task and then returned the deleted tag back.